# QStringDecoder not callable in PySide6

Tags: python, string, encoding, pyside6, qstringdecoder

I can't get the example from the [PySide6 documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QStringConverter.html) working on my system. I am running PySide-6.2 on Ubuntu.

```
toUtf16 = QStringDecoder(QStringConverter.Utf8)
toUtf16('test')
```

Result:

```
TypeError: 'PySide6.QtCore.QStringDecoder' object is not callable
```

Comment: try print(dir(toUtf16)) to see which things it has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug in PySide6. The returned object only has the inherited methods from [QStringConverter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringconverter.html), as can be seen by using `dir`:

```
>>> dec = QtCore.QStringDecoder(QtCore.QStringConverter.Encoding.Utf16)
>>> for x in dir(dec):
...     if x[0].islower(): print(x)
...
hasError
isValid
name
nameForEncoding
requiredSpace
resetState
state
```

So the [decode methods](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringdecoder.html#decode-1) are missing, and the `TypeError` indicates that the `()`-operator overload is missing as well. The `QStringEncoder` class has similar problems.

In PyQt6, everything works as expected:

```
>>> enc = QtCore.QStringEncoder(QtCore.QStringConverter.Encoding.Utf16)
>>> dec = QtCore.QStringDecoder(QtCore.QStringConverter.Encoding.Utf16)
>>> x = enc('text')
>>> x
PyQt6.QtCore.QByteArray(b't\x00e\x00x\x00t\x00')
>>> dec(x)
'text'
```

Of course, you don't really *need* to use these Qt classes, since the equivalent functionality already exists in Python:

```
>>> x = 'text'.encode('utf-16')
>>> x
b'\xff\xfet\x00e\x00x\x00t\x00'
>>> x.decode('utf-16')
'text'
```

Note that Python automatically prepends a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), whereas Qt requires an [additional flag](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringconverter.html#Flag-enum) to get the same behaviour. To get a Qt-style callable object in Python, you can either use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) or a `lambda`:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> enc = partial(str.encode, encoding='utf-16')
>>> # or enc = lambda s: s.encode('utf-16')
>>> dec = partial(bytes.decode, encoding='utf-16')
>>> # or dec = lambda b: b.decode('utf-16')
>>> x = enc('text')
b'\xff\xfet\x00e\x00x\x00t\x00'
>>> dec(x)
'text'
```

NB: to convert a `QByteArray` to a Python `bytes` object, use `bytes(qtbytearray)` or `qtbytearray.data()` (see also: [How to convert a QByteArray to a python string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57665456/984421)).

Comment: Thanks can you tell me how to do the equivalent in Python?

Comment: @Aaron See my updated answer.

Comment: I am getting an error when using your Python method of decoding an actual QByteArray:
TypeError: descriptor 'decode' for 'bytes' objects doesn't apply to a 'PySide6.QtCore.QByteArray' object

Comment: @Aaron Yes, you just need to convert it to python bytes object first, using either `bytes(qtbytearray)` or `qtbytearray.data()`. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks it works :)